# It would be nice to post multi-line shell commands along with an editable one-line version of them

Tags: discussion

Maybe it's not that important, but I think it's worth a quick mention here on meta. Multi-line shell commands are annoying to deal with. Here's a blatant example:

```
find . -type f | \
while read -r filepath; \
do echo "$filepath"; \
done
```

This is a nice way to present a command, but at the same time it goes to the detriment of the command's usability. For example, try, when using it, to change something other than the last line without ending up copy-pasting each single line.

I think it would be nice if such commands would be posted along with an editable one-line version of them, for the ease of copy-paste-edit-run them directly.

Comment: Good idea!  I'll use that from now on!!!  Now you go edit all the answers on the site that contain such commands and add one-liners!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I'd rather not (~1569 posts!), but in case someone is willing to edit their own posts I'll provide a very rough [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/revision/332781/429584/) to find the offending ones ;) You have only one by the way! Congratulations!

Comment: None now!  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I propose that we leave them as-is, and teach the users to avoid the insanity of editing complex commands directly in the shell. Bash, for one, allows us to [edit the current command in an editor](https://superuser.com/a/409155) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (via the readline library).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this. Seconded

Answer (score 0):

There is also <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on some ksh (I think about HP-UX).

- you must be in vi mode (`set -o vi`).

(edit in post because of format)

terminal is gnome-terminal, LTS 14.04.2

```
#stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

what i did: enter a two line command

```
ls |
wc -l
```

run the command,

- then <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, this recall the command in one line, with a ^J
- then <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, this call

  - `vi`, with command on **two lines** (HP-UX),
  - `nano` with command on **one line** (Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm testing this in `ksh` and it's not working (at least in `gnome-terminal`). I think it's a feature of your terminal

Comment: Nope, it's still not working. Which terminal are you on?

Comment: Looks like a `putty` feature, which I can't test; Ctrl+K and Ctrl+K brings the second most recent command run (in `gnome-terminal` with `ksh` and `vi` set). Can you test this in `gnome-terminal` (or any other "local" terminal)?

Comment: I confirm the Ubuntu/nano/set -o vi version 14.04.2

Comment: Then apologize, it must be due to my current (Debian) environment. Gonna test this as soon as I get on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: vi mode, not vi more.

Comment: vi mode, not vi more.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney thank you, vi mode is more of vi !